# SQL, display different items per row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to display the data from two different tables in a certain way using postgresql,but I can't think how it should be done. **I am not allowed to use JOIN and nested commands** The data should be displayed like this:

Country 1

user 1.1

user 1.2
.

.

Country 2

user 2.1

user 2.2

ETC...

Comment: Perhaps a basic `UNION ALL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your tables look like this:

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

Then this should work:

```
select concat('user 1.', id)
from Country1
union all
select concat('user 2.', id)
from Country2
```